# In React, how do you add animations to deletion of a table row because the deletion action will change the app state immediately?

Tags: reactjs, redux

If we actually use a delete action to change the Redux app state to remove that row (say, just an item in array), then the app state will change immediately and the row immediately disappear on screen without any animation.

How do we add 1 animation, such as fade and shrink together, or 2 animations, such as first fade, and then shrink, for the deletion?

---

Some thoughts:

1. Is there any "middleware" (like [`redux-promise`](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-promise) doing AJAX), so we can animate first, and the action will only be sent to the reducers after the animation(s)?
2. Or what if we add a function, doing 1 or 2 animations first, and then when the last promise resolved, then call the action creator?
3. any other possible method?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html). You can define animations to apply to components when they enter or leave the DOM.